# Add sql comment with distributed tracing id globally on mybatis

Tags: mybatis

Is there a cool way to add sql comment like below on Mybatis.

```
SELECT * FROM users; /* TraceID: foo-bar-baz */
```

I would like to add sql comment with TraceID/RequestID/CorrelationID in the context of distributed tracing to all executed sql.
This comment enables to identify a transaction from the comment of a slow query.

I found Interceptor API, but I seem that cannot add commnet.

I seem that we can use scripting like [thymeleaf-scripting](https://github.com/mybatis/thymeleaf-scripting) in this way.
But, We need to add sql comment in all sql...

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: I wrote dirty hack.
It works
https://gist.github.com/wreulicke/ec56feedc1c368024cd892699b4d8c38

Answer (score 1):

In your case, a custom language driver might be a good fit.

### Implementation

The below implementation is mostly the same as the default [`XMLLanguageDriver`](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/scripting/xmltags/XMLLanguageDriver.java).

```java
import org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperEntityResolver;
import org.apache.ibatis.mapping.SqlSource;
import org.apache.ibatis.parsing.PropertyParser;
import org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XNode;
import org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XPathParser;
import org.apache.ibatis.scripting.defaults.RawSqlSource;
import org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.DynamicSqlSource;
import org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.TextSqlNode;
import org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.XMLLanguageDriver;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration;

public class CommentLanguageDriver extends XMLLanguageDriver {

  @Override
  public SqlSource createSqlSource(Configuration configuration,
       XNode script, Class<?> parameterType) {
    // Append comment
    script.getNode().setTextContent(
      script.getNode().getTextContent() + getComment());
    return super.createSqlSource(configuration, script,
      parameterType);
  }

  @Override
  public SqlSource createSqlSource(Configuration configuration,
      String script, Class<?> parameterType) {
    if (script.startsWith("<script>")) {
      XPathParser parser = new XPathParser(script, false,
        configuration.getVariables(), new XMLMapperEntityResolver());
      return createSqlSource(configuration,
        parser.evalNode("/script"), parameterType);
    } else {
      // Append comment
      script = PropertyParser.parse(script + getComment(),
        configuration.getVariables());
      TextSqlNode textSqlNode = new TextSqlNode(script);
      if (textSqlNode.isDynamic()) {
        return new DynamicSqlSource(configuration, textSqlNode);
      } else {
        return new RawSqlSource(configuration, script, parameterType);
      }
    }
  }

  private String getComment() {
    // OGNL expression invoking the static method
    return " /* ${@org.slf4j.MDC@get(\"requestid\")} */";
  }
}
```

The appended comment contains an OGNL expression invoking the static method.
This expression is evaluated at runtime.

### Configuration

To register the custom language driver globally, you need to set `defaultScriptingLanguage` in the config.

```xml
<settings>
  <setting name="defaultScriptingLanguage"
    value="pkg.CommentLanguageDriver" />
</settings>
```

If you are using mybatis-spring-boot-starter, add the following line to your application.properties.

```
default-scripting-language-driver=pkg.CommentLanguageDriver
```